# Does pixate/freestyle font-family changes font size as well?

Tags: pixate

When I set font-family for all labels, fonts are resized to some predefined size.

```
label{
    font-family: "Verdana";
}
```

Is there a way to set font-family only and keep original font-size defined in storyboard file?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue as well, and I don't think there is currently a fix.

You might consider a few other options:

1. Instead of setting custom sizes on all those labels, add a Pixate `styleClass` instead. Then you can do whatever you want to customize the label style in your CSS.
2. If your font size is already set on specific labels in your Storyboard, then just use Verdana in the Storyboard's font selector and don't use Pixate: http://d.pr/i/PQcb

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Pixate defaults to 16pt font-size. There is an issue open for that https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-ios/issues/34.